# Linear regression coefficient changes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a linear regression model described by $y = 0.47x$, then I know that a one unit increase in $x$ translates to a $0.47$ unit increase in $y$. Can I also say that a $0.1$ unit increase in $x$ translates to a $0.047$ unit increase in $y$? Can I say a $q$ unit increase in $x$ translates to a $p$ unit increase in $y$ as long as $\frac{p}{q}$ is $0.47$? Does that make sense to do?

Comment: That is exactly what the equation says. Its graph is a line through the origin with slope $0.47$.

Comment: Yes, assuming your data/context satisfies all the requirements for the type of linear regression model you're using (like [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions)). You can interpret the linear model as saying $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = 0.47\Rightarrow \Delta y = 0.47 \Delta x$, then plug in whatever value you'd like for $\Delta x$.

Comment: Also, be careful not to infer causality - that's determined by the context of your data - and remember that the slope coefficient is meant to be taken as an average, i.e., a $\Delta x$ increase in $x$ is associated with an average increase in $y$ of $0.47\Delta x$.

Comment: Ok so my x and y variables are percentages, representing different interest rates. So I can say that a 1% marginal increase in x translates to a 0.47% increase in y just as much as I can say a 0.1% marginal increase in x translates to 0.047% increase in y???

Comment: Why Ethan so mean to king? Me just confusion last night for some reason.

Comment: The units are percentage points, so it's a percentage point increase, not a percent increase. The reason this matters is that if, for example, $x$ increases from $1\%$ to $2\%$, that's a $1$ percentage point increase, but it's a $100%$ increase.